# How do you cancel the interaction bar?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

When you try to activate/use/open hubs, consoles, boxes and other similiar objects in the game an interaction bar pops up and it takes up to few turns for it to fill up which results in you finishing your interaction with that object.

**How can you cancel the interaction with an object while in the interaction-bar phase?**

I noticed that if enemy hits you it will stop your interaction with the object. I also managed to stop interaction with the objects myself few times, but I really can't remember which button I pressed for it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You press <kbd>Escape</kbd>.

> (The answer was too short to be accepted :s)

Comment: @.@ i think they need to change it from esc

Comment: Thx this works, at least most of the time. Sometimes it still wont cancel the interaction, but ah well.