# Designating targets on BF4 / PS4

Tags: ps4, battlefield-4

On the single player campaign mode of BF4 on PS4 on the first level (Baku) I have difficulty handing off targets to the chopper or members of my squad. I press and hold R1 to bring up the Binoculars but I can't designate/spot the targets. Am I missing a step? I am very new to shooter games and need advice.

Comment: Tap it. No need to hold

Comment: @MadMrCrazy I think that would suffice as an answer.

Comment: @user1337 it's too short

Comment: @MadMrCrazy Allow me to refute your excuse: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108464/how-do-you-cancel-the-interaction-bar/108467#108467

Comment: @user1337 I just posted it. I made it longer so it could be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just tap R1. Don't hold, the holding is to spot them for you to track them behind cover and not your teammates

Comment: Perfect! And... seven more characters to go. You know, the character limit would be useful if it wasn't redundant.

Comment: Yeah, It can be annoying for the old short answers ;)